# how to set text scroll behind the image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-float, wordpress-theming

I am using a custom "pre" tag to create a scrolling text box in wordpress post area.

```
.entry pre {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 616px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color:#333;
    border-style: inset;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#000 url('http://www.emcsaninfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/symcli-back.jpg') no-repeat;
    color:white;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

I am using a image which will position as a heading for the scrolling box. but I am facing an issue here. The text are scrolling over the image. I wanted to send the text behind the image while I scrolling the box down.
Any clue to achieve this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use relevant tags according to question like `css` `html` to get your question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of working wth a background image, you could add a pseudo element with `:before`, set the background to that in stead, and position it absolute on top of the text box. If you give it a z-index it will make the text disappear underneath it on scroll.

If you set up a fiddle with what you have so far, I will be happy to demonstrate.